# Sampling Profiler with Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, profiler

I have some problems in configuring Sampling Profiler (http://www.delphitools.info/samplingprofiler/)

I compiled a test application in debug build configuration, the relevant detailed map file is generated and use debug .dcus option is set to true. Here below the screenshots of the compiler configuration.

[image][image]

I ran the application from Sampling Profiler with the configuration here below and after having performed a few tasks I stopped the profiling. 
[image]

I cannot see any of the lines I coded in the reports and I can see very few units names I coded. The vast majority of the units shown are third part components I use.

[image]

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Asking the obvious, maybe: Are the units in your program part of the project, or are they just being found because they are in the search path? I assume SP wants the former.

Comment: All units are part of the project. They all show up in the Project Manager box in the IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Sampling Profiler does not pick up the browsing path correctly as selected (I have the same issue with a project in XE).

So until that will get fixed you might add the source paths manually ("Custom Source Files Search Path" below the drop down list for the Delphi versions)

However in the function you selected in your screenshot it will not show the correct code because the function is located in the `getmem.inc` file which is included in the `System.pas`.